# Object.defineProperty behaves in safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, cross-browser, frontend

I want to hijack(hook) the `innerHTML` and `nodeValue` property of `Element.prototype` and `Node.prototype` So that i can do something before the set and get action

**innerHTML case：**

```
var ep = Element.prototype;

// {enumerable: true, configurable: true, set , get} // Ch/FF/Op
// {enumerable: true, configurable: false, get: undefined, set: undefined} // Safari
var epDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ep, 'innerHTML');

var epOlderSetter = epDescriptor.set;

/*
  Safari throw:
  TypeError: Attempting to change the getter of an unconfigurable property.
*/
Object.defineProperty(ep, 'innerHTML', {

   set: function(html){

     alert('I want to do something befroe ...');

     epOlderSetter.call(this, html);

   }
 })
```

yeah. i konw the reason. Because the `configurable` in safari is `false` So safari throw error.

**nodeValue case:**

```
var np = Node.prototype;

// {enumerable: true, configurable: true ,get , set} // Ch/FF/Op
// {enumerable: true, configurable: true ,undefined , undefined} // Safari
var npDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(np, 'nodeValue');

var npOlderSetter = npDescriptor.set; // undefined 


Object.defineProperty(np, 'nodeValue', {

   set: function(text){

     alert('I want to do something befroe ...');

     // because npOlderSetter is undefined , so i can't do this.
     // but how can i set the nodeValue to the node ?
     // npOlderSetter.call(this, text);

   }
 })
```

I want to know Is there a workaround or Black magic to achieve my two goals (or one)?

Thanks for any advises

Answer (score 0):

So the problems are:

1. You can't hijack `innerHTML` on Safari because Safari has made it a non-configurable property *(good for them!)*, and
2. You can't hijack `nodeValue` on Safari because it doesn't report the accessor functions back to you when you use `getOwnPropertyDescriptor`, so you can't stash them away and use them from your overridden version

Given those constraints: No, there's nothing you're going to be able to do at the `Element.prototype` level on Safari to take over those two properties.

I would **strongly urge** you not to do so even on hosts (like Chrome) that let you, at least not for any purposes other than debugging in a controlled environment. Most people will tell you not even to augment the prototypes of host-provided objects, much less try to take over their existing properties.

Comment: Thanks.  But how the `MVVM` Framework implement property watch(two ways data-binding) ? yeah, we can hijack native object's property and listen for event for host object rather than hijack host object's property, but if i change the property of the host(dom) object by javascript code  rather than by user event how can i konw the data changes ?

Comment: @pod4g: The MVVM frameworks I've used work exactly as you described: They use the host event system. If you bind a model to a DOM element, and then use JavaScript to modify the DOM element's value directly, they will not see the change. [Example using KO](https://jsfiddle.net/2quku464/), [example using Angular 1](https://jsfiddle.net/jf99Lnqr/). Some frameworks do dirty checks instead (keeping the old value, then comparing with the element's current value). Depending on what you want to monitor, you could probably also use a MutationObserver (but not for the value of an input).